# How to assign keyboard shortcut to open a solution folder from visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to assign a keyboard shortcut to open a solution folder (the one you get when right click on solution name) from Visual Studio. Looking in *keyboard* options in Options didn't help (searched for "folder", for "open" etc.)

Have I missed something ?

Answer (score 1):

This is it:

> ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Project.OpenFolderInWindowsExplorer

It works, but I'm sure how you get the solution selected first?

Please let us know if you can solve it elegantly, I'm interested because I don't currently use AnhkSVN or VisualSVN, I prefer TortoiseSVN, but it would be nice to open the solution folder since that's normally the root.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a keyboard shortcut to a macro using [this example](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/8)

> **Assigning a Keyboard Shortcut to Macro in VS**
>
> Last time I forgot to mention one
>   important thing - how to assign a
>   keyboard shortcut to your macro. Often
>   you don’t need any button for your
>   macro, the shortcut is enough. Or you
>   can have both. As I already wrote,
>   macro is similar to any named command.
>   So to assign a shortcut to it:
>
> 1. Go to menu **Tools - Options**… and select **Environment - Keyboard**.
>      [alt text http://www.helixoft.com/blog/wp-content/uploaded/keyboard_options.png](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/wp-content/uploaded/keyboard_options.png)
> 2. Find your macro in the list of commands. All macro names start with
>      “Macro.”. To filter out other commands
>      enter your macro name in the **Show
>      commands containing** field. If your
>      macro is named test as in our example
>      then type *test*. Select your macro.
> 3. Go to **Press shortcut key(s)** field and press your shortcut. If the
>      shortcut is already in use, you will
>      see it. Press **Assign** button.
>
> Remember that you cannot change or
>   assign the shortcut if you are using
>   predefined keyboard mapping scheme.
>   You will be warned in this case. You
>   must create a copy of current scheme
>   and use that copy. Press **Save As…**
>   button under **Keyboard mapping**
>   scheme and give it some name. Then
>   select this new scheme.

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't a keyboard shortcut defined for that, but Visual Studio has excellent macro support, and you can create your own macro to do that.

There's a Macro Recorder feature that you can use. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa301743(VS.71).aspx) explains how to use the Macro Recorder.